# What does $d f_x^n v^s$ mean?

Tags: dynamical-systems

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold, $U \subset M$ be open, $f: U \to M$ a $C^1$ diffeomorphism. Let $\Lambda \subset U$ be compact and $f$-invariant, $\lambda \in (0,1)$ and $C > 0$, and a family of subspaces $E^s(x) \subset T_x M$ and $E^u (x) \subset T_x M$. Then one of the requirements of $\Lambda$ to be hyperbolic, is the following:
$$
\| df_x^n v^s\| \leq C \lambda^n \|v^s\|
$$
for every $v^s \in E^s(x)$. I am wondering what the notation $d f_x^n v^s$ means in this context. Is it the derivative (Jacobian) of $f^n$ evaluated in $x$ and applied to $v^s$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map
$$
d_xf\colon T_xM\to T_{f(x)}M
$$
(or with your notation $df_x$) is defined by
$$
d_xf \gamma'(0)=(f\circ\gamma)'(0)
$$
for any differentiable curve $\gamma$ with $\gamma(0)=x$. The map $d_xf^n$ is defined in a similar manner.

When $M=\mathbb R^n$ the map $d_xf^n$ is indeed the Jacobian matrix (you should write "Jacobian" for the determinant of the Jacobian matrix).